# /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find?

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile, ld

I study C language in ubuntu 18.04(gcc 7.3)

When the `make all` command is entered, this error occurrs:

> /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: can not find -lkeccak

The `Makefile` is as follows.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-03 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse2avx -mavx2 -march=native -std=c99

all:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Lizard.c main.c randombytes.c sha512.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o Lizard Lizard.o main.o randobytes.o sha512.o -lkeccak

run: all
    ./Lizard

new:
    make clean
    make all
    ./Lizard
```

Currently the `libkeccak.a` file is in the same directory as the `Makefile` and 
it is also in the `/usr/include` directory.

I do not know the solution method at all.

Please, Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-l` option is for linking dynamic libraries (like `libkeccak.so`). Static libraries are linked into the executable already if they're in one of the "standard" directories, so there's no need to provide the option `-lkeccak`.

If you want to explicitly tell GCC to link a static library,

```
gcc -l:/path/to/libkeccak.a
```